# Parse HTM page from POST method

Tags: python, html, parsing, post

I have a page. When I click on some button on the page, some data from another HTM file is loaded via `POST` method. The link on this page is not changing. How can I get the loaded data?

Comment: See what is posted, HTTP POST the same data and parse the response. Take a look at [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html).

Comment: @That1Guy thank you! It helped!